# download apk using desktop / laptop

Tags: android

I'm working on a project now which requires a lot of apks.

I need to download APKS from android markets (not limited to Google Play) using my computer.

I found this [post](http://codekiem.com/2012/02/24/apk-downloader/) that might help me, but im still looking for other tools/website(which will allow to download FREE apps in the desktop) that can solve my problem.

Im also targetting apks that can be dowloaded(was made) in Europe and or other continent except Asia. Could you give point the market which contains these kinds of APKS?

What I need to do is to make a system that will analyze each apk. tell if the app is consuming too much resources (battery, memory usage etc.)

Comment: I think you might have to give some context to this.  Your motives are probably good but some people might interpret what you are tying to do as promoting software theft.  A lot of people will not be willing to help unless you explain why you need to do this.

Comment: i see. ill do some changes with the question.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not possible.  You would have to install and run each application to measure it's impact on resources.  Static analysis (simply downloading then inspecting) will tell you little.

Comment: yes, i know that I need to install the apps to be able to know if its eating up the resources. But before I do that, I want to gather all APKs that I could gather then later feed it to the system. downloading the apk using desktop is just the sourcing phase of the system. Im gonna run the APK to emulator.

Comment: OK, got it.  I think you are out of luck.  Direct downloading of APKs from legal app sites will almost certainly be a violation of their terms and conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension you linked is based on a reverse engineered Android Market client. You can easily find the sources. There are also PHP and Python ports. However, it is using the old Market/Play protocol and some apps may not be accessible. See their Google group for details.

Generally, to do this, you need to pretend to be the Google Play client and use the same protocol it does. Additionally, downloading too fast will get you banned, so you will need to rate limit your app and/or use multiple Google accounts.

And of course, you can simply get a device with a lot of memory, install a bunch of apps, and then pull them off the device for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Found these articles that enumerate app stores and some of them allow user to download apk's in PC

http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/04/featured/download-apk.html

http://mobiputing.com/2011/06/17-places-to-download-android-apps/

Answer (score 0):

you can visit apk search engine such as http://apkdroid.in you can find any apk file and download it directly to your PC